# Setting Height dependent on Height of parent

Tags: maui

In my .NET MAUI App I‘d would like to set the Height of an inner element based on the height of its parent. I tried in OnSizeAllocated(..), but there the parent seems not Layouter finally.

So, is there an event that allows me to set the size of an inner element when its parent layout (including Height of the parent based on its layouting options) is finalized?

What I wanted to do is something like setting the height of an inner element a bit beyond the height a lower element. On another view there is an own navigation bar at the bottom which is on top of other elements (regarding ZIndex) and when I would do it with a layout it would range to the bottom, but then parts are covered by this Bottom Navigation bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried below?

// Attach the SizeChanged event to the parent view
this.SizeChanged += OnParentSizeChanged;

Comment: Well, yes and no - so your answer is absolutely right, I can add that event and align based on that. The more I think about it, the more I suppose I am asking for a different question. This is probably, how would I realize the HeightRequests for Children on different platforms and orientations. When I look at my OnSizeAllocated right now it is aligned with ```InnerBorder.HeightRequest = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height * 0.275;``` and fits for **iOS** but on **Android** in my simulator it is more or less ```InnerBorder.HeightRequest = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height * 0.3;```

Comment: So already here is a little difference and with 0.275 it would not work and overlap as it should. Basically, I think I am asking the question what would be a good method to set such a HeightRequest that can not be realized with Layouts alone when it comes to different DisplaySizes. Also the numbers I get are totally different - in OnSizeAllocated I get about 760 after multiplikation with 0.275 whereas I get about 560 when doing ```InnerBorder.HeightRequest = parentGrid.Height;```. Is there a good way to solve it and meeting the layout requirements with different Display-Sizes and platforms?

Comment: Or would it be better to get the Height of the Parent and do not multiply but add a fixed factor to get to the final HeightRequest for the Child-Element?